# Is it right to use Blender for such kind of animation? Animated caption for video

Tags: animation

I want to make animated caption for video. It will be in the lower third part of frame.

Example. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0lpjHQRWEc&t=28

0:30. Two rectangles appeared - blue and light gray. Next step letters appeared on rectangles. Next step letters disappeared. Next step rectangles disappeared.

I am not going to copy one to one this animation. I want to use another colors, another font.

Is it right to use Blender for such kind of animation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will work. There are probably customizable effects in video editing softwares that will do a similar thing.

Cons

- Blender isn't specialized for this kind of task. It is more generic to solve tasks like it.
- Blender has no in built function to do this. You will have to build it from scratch using geometry or bitmaps.

Pros

- You will have ultimate control over everything
- Blender is free
- The community is great

In a video editing software you can maybe find a title effect that is (almost) like this. You can edit the text. You can change the colors. You can maybe change the timing. But you may not get exactly this.

So it comes down to what kind of person you are, and how long time you have.

- If you are picky, have time and want to get everything right. Use blender.
- If you are less picky or are in a hurry. Don't use blender.

Comment: Thank you, Gunslinger. I took in attention your words. I want to use Blender. Rectangles are flat. Is it right to make animation of flat figures in Blender?

Comment: @Konskoo yes, flat is very easy to work with. Come back here and start new questions, more specific.